# Rails AggregateRoot "on" handlers not detected as instance methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorbet, rails-event-store

In Rails event store, `AggregateRoot` has DSL methods that result in blocks with this shape:

```
class X
  extend AggregateRoot::OnDSL

  class MyEvent < RailsEventStore::Event; end

  on MyEvent do |event|
    # Code
  end
end
```

Inside that block, there's access to the class instance data. But sorbet don't know about it.

Is there a way to tell Sorbet that that block will be injected as an instance method?

I can mark every use of fields or methods as `T.unsafe()`, but that would remove the typing from it, and adding a cast makes the code harder to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`T.bind`](https://sorbet.org/docs/type-assertions#tbind) to communicate to Sorbet that `self` has a particular type in a particular block:

```rb
class X
  extend AggregateRoot::OnDSL

  class MyEvent < RailsEventStore::Event; end

  on MyEvent do |event|
    T.bind(self, MyEvent)
    # Code
  end
end
```

More generally, you can add a shim which specifies the type of a DSL API like this, and [specify the type the proc will be bound to](https://sorbet.org/docs/procs#annotating-the-self-type-with-tprocbind), like: `T.proc.bind(TheTypeOfSelfInTheBlock).params(...).returns(...)`.

In this case, it's a bit tricky for `AggregateRoot::OnDSL.on`, if not impossible, for two reasons:

1. `on` takes a `*event_klasses`. You can't be sure which event class triggered your block, so you don't statically know which of the `event_klasses` the event passed to your block will be.
2. The type of `event_klasses` should be `event_klasses: T.class_of(RailsEventStore::Event)`. Even if it were one singular value, you would need the generics system to let you express that the block's argument is specifically the type of `event_klasses` (and not just any `RailsEventStore::Event`). I don't think that's currently possible.

Comment: Oh, T.bind was added aroung `0.5.6395` and we're using `0.5.6300`. But it would work I suppose. Also, the block is bound to the class itself, not the event, so it would be pretty simple.
I'll check the T.proc.bind, it exists in my version and it should be simpler. Thanks!

Edit: The T.proc.bind wouldn't work I think, as "TheTypeOfSelfInTheBlock" isn't a specific type. Unless there's a meta-type in Sorbet that means "The class where the DSL was invoked", I'm not sure how to use it

Comment: @Iván It would need to involve generics, something like: `type_parameters(:Event).params(event_klasses: T.type_parameter(:Event), block: T.proc.bind(T.class_of(T.type_parameter(:Event)).params(event: type_parameters(:Event)).void).void` The issue is that `T.class_of` only works for concrete class types, and not generic type parameters.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something, but the class that will be bound to self, in your example, is X. You can ignore the events thing, it was just an example of the real DSL

Comment: The events example is complex because of the need for generics. Can you give me a more concrete example that's more similar to exactly what you're trying to do? "but the class that will be bound to self, in your example" I don't quite understand what you mean by this. "The class" is not bound any which way. Either `self` (in the context of a block) is bound to a particular static type with `T.bind(self, SomeClass`, or a proc is declared that its body is evaluated in a particular context (which causes `self` to be bound automatically for you` with `T.prop.bind(...)...`)

Comment: The "on" DSL injects the block as a instance method of the X class, so Self = X there. With T.bind it would be `T.bind(self, X)`. The event parameter can be ignored in the example

Comment: Ohhhhh I misunderstood it. Oh, that’s easy, you would just annotate the block as `T.proc.bind(T.self_type)…` (or possibly `T.attached_class`, I don’t remember, try both)